# UpdatePanel slow update on certain server

Tags: .net, iis, caching, updatepanel

I've been using an UpdatePanel to asynchronously load a list with entries based on a category chosen in a DropDownList-control. In my dev environment everything works smoothly and I've also deployed it to a different server and tried it there without any problems.

However, when I today deployed it to a third server things started to get really slow. The page takes roughly 500 ms to load (with a default view of list items in the UpdatePanel), but when switching category in the DropDownList the UpdatePanel takes around 20 seconds to load the new results. The second server (which works great) and the third server (which is super slow) has a very similar setup which leads me to believe that there is some kind of cache setting (or other setting) on the third server that I'm missing.

I'm aware that the UpdatePanel reloads the whole page, but how can there be such a vast difference between the two servers? Worst case scenario  I will have to switch the UpdatePanel for some other solution but it just seems like there is something I'm missing on the third server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this. We have two HttpHandlers that makes asynchronous requests to an external server for getting some external data back to the site. However, on the new server the firewall had not been configured to allow these requests to be made. This for some reason caused the whole Update Panel reload to wait for the HttpHandlers to timeout before performing the update.
Stupid problem but you always learn something.